# Delphi and using Teamspeak SDK read returned multi dim arrays

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to read returned arrays from the TeamSpeak3 SDK, some of the methods returns arrays that are null terminated and multi dimensional with a mix of data types.

What "delhpi" structure should I pass as parameter and how can I read the returned values back in the a matching structure? a la.

```
type
  TDeviceInfo = record
    DeviceId : string; // maybe an integer
    DeviceName : string;
  end;

  TDeviceInfoArr = array of TDeviceInfo

  // or maybe
  TDeviceInfoArr = array of array[0..1] of string; 

var
  DeviceArr : array of TDeviceInfoArr;
```

This is what the SDK Documentation says.

To get a list of all available playback and capture devices for the specified mode, call

```cpp
unsigned int ts3client_getPlaybackDeviceList(modeID, result); 
const char* modeID;   
char**** result;  

unsigned int ts3client_getCaptureDeviceList(modeID, result); 
const char* modeID;  
char**** result;
```

Parameters
• modeID
Defines the playback/capture mode to use. For different modes there might be different device lists. Valid modes are returned by
ts3client_getDefaultPlayBackMode / s3client_getDefaultCaptureMode and  ts3client_getPlaybackModeList / ts3client_getCaptureModeList.

• result
Address of a variable that receives a NULL-terminated array { { char* deviceName, char* deviceID }, { char* deviceName, char* deviceID }, ... , NULL }.
Unless the function returns an error, the elements of the array and the array itself need to be freed using ts3client_freeMemory.
Returns ERROR_ok on success, otherwise an error code as defined in public_errors.h. In case of an error, the result array is uninitialized and must not be released.

**Example to query all available playback devices:**

```cpp
char * defaultMode;
if (ts3client_getDefaultPlayBackMode( & defaultMode) == ERROR_ok) {
  char * * * array;
  if (ts3client_getPlaybackDeviceList(defaultMode, & array) == ERROR_ok) {
    for (int i = 0; array[i] != NULL; ++i) {
      printf("Playback device name: %s\n", array[i][0]); /* First element: Device name */
      printf("Playback device ID: %s\n", array[i][1]); /* Second element: Device ID */
      /* Free element */
      ts3client_freeMemory(array[i][0]);
      ts3client_freeMemory(array[i][1]);
      ts3client_freeMemory(array[i]);
    }
    ts3client_freeMemory(array); /* Free complete array */
  } else {
    printf("Error getting playback device list\n");
  }
} else {
  printf("Error getting default playback mode\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'm going to ignore error handling because I think we handled that in your last question. And I'm going to assume that `ts3client_getDefaultPlayBackMode` presents no problems.

So that leaves `ts3client_getPlaybackDeviceList`. Import it like this:

```
function ts3client_getPlaybackDeviceList(modeID: PAnsiChar; 
  out result: PPPAnsiChar): Cardinal; cdecl; external '...';
```

You will likely need to define `PPPAnsiChar`.

```
type
  PPPAnsiChar = ^PPAnsiChar;
  PPAnsiChar = ^PAnsiChar;
```

You might find that the RTL already defines `PPAnsiChar`.

So, next to calling the function. First of all declare a variable to hold the array, and so others to help iterate:

```
var
  arr, myarr: PPPAnsiChar;
  p: PPAnsiChar;
```

Then call the function:

```
ts3client_getPlaybackDeviceList(modeID, arr);
myarr := arr;
while myarr^ <> nil do
begin
  p := myarr^;
  Writeln('Playback device name: ', p^);
  ts3client_freeMemory(p^);
  inc(p);
  Writeln('Playback device ID: ', p^);
  ts3client_freeMemory(p^);
  ts3client_freeMemory(myarr^);
  inc(myarr);
end;
ts3client_freeMemory(arr);
```

This code is really quite vile I'm sure that you will agree. If you have a modern version of Delphi then you can enable pointer math to make it read better.

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}

ts3client_getPlaybackDeviceList(modeID, arr);
i := 0;
while arr[i] <> nil do
begin
  Writeln('Playback device name: ', arr[i][0]);
  Writeln('Playback device ID: ', arr[i][1]);
  ts3client_freeMemory(arr[i][0]);
  ts3client_freeMemory(arr[i][1]);
  ts3client_freeMemory(arr[i]);
  inc(i);
end;
ts3client_freeMemory(arr);
```

Although this code is better, it will never win a beauty contest.

Remember that I've neglected all error checking. You'll need to add that.

Comment: In you first solution:
We have a pointer to a memory location (myarr) and that pointer points to a pointer with the first (p) element of the deviceinfo (name).
So everytime we move myarr pointer we need to move the deviceinfo pointer p one to fetch the deviceid.
Hmmm.... boiler plate...

Second solution looks like Delphi :)
Appears much more "direct" just moving the main pointer.

Now I only I have a single question left, and that's how to build that same structure to parse it to the SDK - but that's gonna be a new question.


Thank you so much - very very helpful!

Comment: So, are you a French cyclist?

Comment: What.. You think I behave like one?? :) No I'm a Danish cyclist ;) If you refer to my avatar then it was captured at mt. ventoux just after I have climbed it for the 3rd. time one one day, I'm the proud member of this exclusive club  
[Club des Cinglés du Mont-Ventoux](http://www.clubcinglesventoux.org/en.html)

Comment: I've not even done the Ventoux once even though I regularly holiday within sight of it. I know another guy in that club. Hard work to join!

Comment: No it doesn't come easy at all but is doable if you want to, you should do it if you like cycling, it is an extreme experience and very satisfactory.  I wasn't lucky with the weather 0 deg and storming at the summit, although dry. On the last right hand corner I was blown over by the wind, there were other people laying in the corner but I thought I was better and stronger so I headed into the wind - not very wise... I just barely saved my bike for flying off the edge, real drama ;) but great to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Based on David's suggesstions I found the following code working, thanks David!

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}
procedure TfrmMain.RequestPlaybackDevices;
var
  arr, myarr: PPPAnsiChar;
  p: PPAnsiChar;
  defaultmode : PAnsiChar;
  i : Integer;
begin
  try
    ts3check(ts3client_getDefaultPlayBackMode(@defaultmode));
    ts3check(ts3client_getPlaybackDeviceList(defaultMode, @arr));
    try
      i := 0;
      while arr[i] <> nil do
      begin
        LogMsg(format('Playback device name: %s',[UTF8ToUnicodeString(arr[i][0])]));
        LogMsg(format('Playback device ID: %s',[UTF8ToUnicodeString(arr[i][1])]));
        ts3client_freeMemory(arr[i][0]);
        ts3client_freeMemory(arr[i][1]);
        ts3client_freeMemory(arr[i]);
        inc(i);
      end;
    finally
      ts3client_freeMemory(arr);
    end;
  except
    on e: exception do LogMsg(Format('Error RequestPlaybackDevices: %s', [e.Message]));
  end;
end;
{$POINTERMATH OFF}
```

Comment: You need to stop automatically translating pointers directly, in my view. ts3client_getDefaultPlayBackMode should have an out parameter. I'm sure there are many more instances where you do this. And you really really must not have this code in your gui. Put it in a separate unit.